# Alternative type of calculation mean and variance of a distribution

Tags: probability-theory

I want help to prove the type of variance. Maybe the Tonelli-Fubini theorem could hels us.

[image]

Comment: It is not clear precisely what you are asking for help with

Comment: Sorry,it is my first question here. I want to prove the type of variance.